# trying to run sudo apache2ctl restart installing koha

Tags: 12.04

I am new in ubuntu, I am trying to install koha, so I tried to restart apache2 with ...

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

but I get the following error ...

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/OPAC_WWW_DIR] does not exist [Tue Jul 09 11:14:58] 
[error] (EAI 5)No address associated with hostname:could not resolve host name 
WEBSERVER_HOST__IP:WEBSERVER_PORT_LIBRARIAN__--ignoring Warning: DocumentRoot 
[/etc/apache2/INTRANET_WWW_DIR] does not exist syntax error on line 108 
of /etc/apache2/sitse-enabled/koha: 
The port number "WEBSERVER_HOST:__WEBSERVER_PORT_LIBRARIAN__"
is outside the appropriate range (i.e, 1..65535) Action 'restart' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Koha is packaged for Debian and Ubuntu, so I suggest installing it by following the instructions here:

http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages

After the package is installed, you can use the `koha-create` to set up a Koha database, which includes create an Apache virtualhost configuration for that database.

The fact that strings like `__WEBSERVER_PORT_LIBRARIAN__` appear in your Apache configuration suggest that you had tried installing Koha from a tarball or git checkout.  During the installation process, Koha's installer creates an Apache configuration file to put in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` by taking a template file and substituting in values that you supplied when you ran `Makefile.PL`.  However, it appears that you put the template into `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, not the generated Apache configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message sort of tells you the problem(s)

1. "DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/INTRANET_WWW_DIR] does not exist"

What is the syntax of your DocumentRoot ? FYI, normally you put such things in /var/www rather then /etc/apache2/INTRANET_WWW_DIR. Post line 108 of /etc/apache2/sitse-enabled/koha if  you need help.

1. "The port number "WEBSERVER_HOST:**WEBSERVER_PORT_LIBRARIAN**" is outside the appropriate range (i.e, 1..65535) Action 'restart' failed.

This suggests you are trying to run on a non-standard port. Normally Apache uses port 80, but it sounds as if you defined a port higher then 65535 ???.

Again , post your config file(s) if you need further assistance.

Comment: It actually looks like the port is `__WEBSERVER_PORT_LIBRARIAN__` which is out of the 1..65535 range. Also how could the typo crawl into the error message: `/etc/apache2/sitse-enabled/`?